# Change default location of node_modules in new ASP.NET5 project structure?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am planning to use npm to manage all my JavaScript dependencies and get rid of bower from my ASP.NET5 project. I need npm to create node_modules folder in wwwroot location rather than its default location. I tried using .npmrc but VS2015 don't recognize it. Is there a way configure this?

Comment: See, if this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553723/common-wwwroot-folder-for-multiple-websites-in-mvc-6

Comment: @eadam but it didn't helped. I wonder if we I can override it by defining a key in .csproj somewhere?